# apostrophe cms - customize page settings

Tags: javascript, apostrophe-cms

I want to add meta-key and meta-description fields to the page setting dialog, and then render them to the page.
I was able to find that one can do something like this in the page template (html) file:

```
{% extends data.outerLayout %}
{% block extraHead %}
    <meta name="description" content="this is the page description" />
{% endblock %}
```

But how do I allow the end user to insert these values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so after looking in the [apostrophe-sandbox](https://github.com/punkave/apostrophe-sandbox) demo site I was able to discover the answer.
I added under the `lib/modules` folder in my project a new folder called `apostrophe-custom-pages`, and inside that I added an `index.js` file that looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  beforeConstruct: function(self, options) {
    options.addFields = [
      {
        name: 'metaDescription',
        label: 'Meta Description',
        type: 'string'
      },
      {
        name: 'metaTags',
        label: 'Meta Tags',
        type: 'string'
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Then, inside my page html template I added:

```
{% block extraHead %}
  <meta name="description" content="{{ data.page.metaDescription}}" />
  <meta name="tags" content="{{ data.page.metaTags}}" />
{% endblock %}
```

That's it. It works. Now I can provide SEO support. Hurray! :)

Comment: Boom! Glad the sandbox was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

here is an improved way to do it:

```
{% block extraHead %}
 <meta name="description" content="{{ data.page.metaDescription | truncate(146, true, "..") | safe }}" />
{% endblock %}
```

#### What we did here:

- we truncate meta description to a specific length (in this instance 146 characters, but you can change that);
- we add a nice .. at the end that one is used to when googling around;
- we output everything as "safe" - this takes care of showing certain symbols or characters as unicode / html strings. Though it can be theoretically be abused.

See the screenshot to illustrate the last point: [image: Just a screenshot]